# VR for matlab, MS excel and 3D curve

Tags: excel, matlab, 3d, virtual, gear-vr

Is there anyway of connecting Matlab with VR headset? I mean specifically Samsung Gear VR (I would use mirroring from PC to Samsung Gear VR with compatible Samsung phone). I have a 3D curve created using Matlab and I am trying to find a way how to connect it with VR headset, as well I need to be able to rotate with the curve.
Note: Don't worry, I have been using google, I just haven't found anything yet.

Different option: Is it possible to create a 3D curve in Micsoroft Excel (as well be possible to customize it and rotate with it)? I have three columns: X, Y and Z.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the (cheap) Leap Motion Controller / hand tracking device to achieve this; I don't have any experience with the Samsung Gear VR devices, but they might be used in combination with the leap motion controller according to the leap motion fora.

See also:

https://github.com/jeffsp/matleap

https://community.leapmotion.com/